# Swift 4 Cocoa reading formatted data into variable

Tags: swift, cocoa, formatted-input

I need to read some formatted data from a string and store it in two variables. The string has this format:

```
data = "(1234),(-567)"
```

The numbers are of varying lengths and signs. I feel like this should be simple. It would be easy in C:

```
scanf(data, "(%d),(%d)", num1, num2)
```

But in Swift, I'm pulling my hair out trying to find an easy way to do this. As suggested in other answers, I've tried:

```
data.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
```

However this overlooks minus signs. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Scanner`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner) when you need `scanf`-like behavior:

```
let data = "(1234),(-567)"

var num1: CInt = 0
var num2: CInt = 0
let scanner = Scanner(string: data)
if
    scanner.scanString("(", into: nil),
    scanner.scanInt32(&num1),
    scanner.scanString("),(", into: nil),
    scanner.scanInt32(&num2),
    scanner.scanString(")", into: nil)
{
    print(num1, num2)
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like regular expressions:

```
let data = "(1234),(-567)"
let pattern = "\\((.*?)\\)"
let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
let result = reg.matches(in: data, options: [], 
    range: NSMakeRange(0, data.utf16.count))
let numstrings = result.map {(data as NSString).substring(with: $0.rangeAt(1))}
let nums = numstrings.map {Int($0)!} // I'm feeling lucky
// [1234, -567]
```